# Auto-update specific cell in a spreadsheet depending on answer from a Google Form Response

Tags: google-forms

My spreadsheet has two tabs

1. Google Form responses
2. Schedule of regular tasks

The Google Form gathers data about a specific task and records the date of completion for that task.  When a user has made a form submission, I then want the "Date Last Completed" cell next to that specific task in tab 2 to update with the date entered in the form submission.

In effect, the date cell in tab 2 needs to have some sort of formula or otherwise to scan the date column and task name column in tab 1 to update to the latest date entered for that specific task if that makes sense?